# json object handling in JS

Tags: javascript, json

My given json object is as follows:

```
resultTable = [
    {
        id: "005470021180",
        balance: "0.00",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD",
        entitlements: [

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "005470021288",
        balance: "0.00",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD"
    },
    {
        id: "005470044628",
        balance: "-72,116.01",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD"
    },
    {
        id: "40592000495201",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "Borrowing",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    },
    {
        id: "40592000495202",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "Borrowing",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    },
    {
        id: "40592000495203",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "Investing",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    },
    {
        id: "40592000495204",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "INVESTING",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    },
    {
        usd_balance: "1,080.27",
        id: "55300070",
        accountName: "Scotia iTRADE",
        category: "INVESTING",
        cad_balance: "272,166.59"
    }
];
```

I need an output in JS as :

```
resulttable = [
{
    "Banking": {
        id: "005470021180",
        balance: "0.00",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD",
        entitlements: [

        ]
    },
    {
        id: "005470021288",
        balance: "0.00",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD"
    },
    {
        id: "005470044628",
        balance: "-72,116.01",
        accountName: "Money Master",
        category: "Banking",
        currency: "CAD"
    }
},
{
    "Borrowing": {
        id: "40592000495201",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "Borrowing",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    },
    {
        id: "40592000495202",
        accountName: "Business Loan",
        category: "Borrowing",
        cad_balance: "0.00"
    }
},
{
    ""INVESTING":{
            {
            id : "40592000495203",
            accountName : "BusinessLoan",
            category : "Investing",
            cad_balance : "0.00"
            },
            {
            id : "40592000495204",
            accountName : "BusinessLoan",
            category : "INVESTING",
            cad_balance : "0.00"
        },
        {
            usd_balance : "1,080.27",
            id : "55300070",
            accountName : "ScotiaiTRADE",
            category : "INVESTING",
            cad_balance : "272,166.59"
        }} ];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you also properly format the code in your question?

Comment: Looks like he wants to sort the array..

Comment: nope, he wants to categorise the items

Comment: fine... categorize the items...  His output format looks odd tho

Comment: The input `resultTable` as shown is _not_ JSON. ([There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)) The output format shown is not valid JavaScript: you have nested objects that are supposed to be arrays, i.e., in some places you've used curly brackets `{}` where you should have square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Yes yes... One'd assume that the op's not familiar with the topic and have some misconceptions. But your comment on {}'s and []'s not very clear to someone new to these things.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function (input)
{
    var output = new Object();
    for(var i = 0, len=input.length; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(typeof output[input[i].category] === 'undefined')
        {
            output[input[i].category] = [];
        }
        output[input[i].category].push(input[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

input would be your starting object, and it returns the output in the structure you want.
Or at least what I think you'd wanted.